# Is there a way to specify or force data type of calculated member?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, adomd.net, mdxclient

I've got data type of every measure in my cube specified as `Currency`. 
I've also got calculated members, some of them have `iif(isempty([Measures].[Measure1]) or [Measures].[Measure1] = 0, null, 100 * [Measures].[Measure2] / [Measures].[Measure1])` logic.

I'm accessing this cube using [MdxClient](https://github.com/DynamicTyped/MdxClient) (it uses [`AdomdCommand.ExecuteXmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124391(v=sql.110).aspx) internally) and have noticed that some of this calculated members are returned as `xsd:double` not `xsd:decimal`. So I assume that they are calculated as `Double` not `Currency`. Query results are mapped to strongly typed data set at client side, so returned type is important to me.

I can 'force' ssas to return `xsd:decimal` by wrapping each of calulated members with `VBA!CDec` or just `CDec`, but this seriously degrades perfomance.

Is there a smarter way to set or force calculated member to be `Currency`? Or at least be returned as `xsd:decimal` by `AdomdCommand.ExecuteXmlReader`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not possible to set the data type of your calculated measures. The data type will be assigned based on the measures used in your calculation as well as the type of calculation you are performing.

Answer (score 0):

Have the code of calculated member this way:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrencyMeasure] 
AS
iif(isempty([Measures].[Measure1]) or 
[Measures].[Measure1] = 0, null, 
100 * [Measures].[Measure2] / [Measures].[Measure1]), FORMAT_STRING="Currency"
```

Comment: Thank you, but you're talking about format string, not the data type of calculated member.